# TBODY scrolls on focus in FireFox

Tags: html, css

## HTML

```
<html>
<body>
    <div style="width:100%; height: 300px; overflow: auto;">
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" style="width:100%;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Col1</td>
                    <td>Col2</td>
                    <td>Col3</td>
                    <td>Col4</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody tabindex="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>Col1</td>
                    <td>Col2</td>
                    <td>Col3</td>
                    <td>Col4</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

## Problem

In FireFox, when you click on a row, it puts focus onto the tbody, causing the containing div to produce a horizontal scrollbar which scrolls for 1 pixel.

## Question

How can I prevent the horizontal scrolling showing up when the row is clicked? I could put `"overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto;"` on the containing div instead, but what if the div really does need to scroll horizontally? Does anyone know of a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to prevent the dotted lines from showing up, try this:

```
<style>
    table *:focus{
        outline:0;
    }
</style>
```

Good luck.